# Send each character of array to each number of process in mpi

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

array of character does not send character to each process

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Get my rank in the communicator
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    char *a;
    int broadcast_root = 0;
    if (my_rank == broadcast_root) {

        printf("enter any string\n");
        a = (char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%[^\n]", a);
    }
    char *a1 = new char[8];
    MPI_Scatter(&a, 1, MPI_CHAR, &a1, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("process %d : %c\n", my_rank, *a1);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

when the code is run the process 0 show the first character
but I need
input: abcd
output: a
b
c
d

Comment: Buffers needs to be a `sometype*`. Since `char *a` you should not send `&a` but `a` itself.

Comment: MPI_Scatter(a, 1, MPI_CHAR, a1, 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    result is same it's not working

Comment: Do the other processes output anything? More specifically, are you sure you  are running multiple processes?

Comment: it works for me ... how do you test your program? i do `echo abcd | mpirun -np 4 a.out`

Comment: yes work for me after a restart of my pc thanks man